# Second half of the day (4-6 p.m.)

Tags: generic-term

Is there special word to describe second half of the day? 
For example I would like to make an appointment with a friend about 4-6 p.m. Is there general term for this or can just "afternoon" be used?

Comment: **Afternoon** is *already* the second half of the day.  The other half of the daylight period is *morning*.

Comment: The AM is one half of the day, while the PM is the other half, each exactly twelve hours long. A two-hour segment cannot be referred to as the second half of the day. It merely therein occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can there be an **exact time-range** ?

> Even if there is, it can vary according to the hours of daylight at each time of year.

I am interested to see what comments you get,however, I may not be abysmally wrong if I say:

- Early afternoon: 1 to 3pm, Late afternoon   4 to 5pm, Early evening    5 to 7 pm*.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably say "late afternoon."

Comment: Definitely the "later afternoon". Aka "around teatime".

Answer (score 0):

'Late afternoon' (if it's light then) or 'early evening' if the sun is setting or has set but afternoon is OK.

for an appointment, you'd probably want to specify the clock time rather than a word. You don't want to specify a meeting time with 'afternoon' because it is too long a stretch.

> "Let's meet at the bank lobby for the heist later this afternoon"

will be more likely to result in coordination difficulties. Better to specify the time

Comment: Mitch, Why you used 'has set'? it shouldn't be 'has been set'? what is the difference between them? I have a serious problem about the times of verbs!

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri "The sun sets" -> "The sun has set". "The book is set on the table (by someone)" -> "The book has been set on the table".